# Scraping Google News results with Python and Beautiful Soup retrieves only the first page without headlines

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape headlines and paragraph texts from Google News search page based on the term searched.
I want to do that for first *n* pages.

I have wrote a piece of code for scraping the first page only, but I do not know how to modify my `url` so that I can go to other pages to (page 2, 3 ...). That's the **first problem** that I have.

**Second problem** is that I do not know how to scrape headlines. It always returns me empty list. I have tried multiple solutions but it always returns me empty list. (I do not think that page is dynamic).

On the other hand scraping paragraph text below the headline works perfectly.
Can you tell me how to fix these two problems?

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

term = 'cocacola'

# this is only for page 1, how to go to page 2?
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={0}&source=lnms&tbm=nws'.format(term)

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# I think that this is not javascipt sensitive, its not dynamic            
headline_results = soup.find_all('a', class_="l lLrAF")
#headline_results = soup.find_all('h3', class_="r dO0Ag") # also does not work
print(headline_results) #empty list, IDK why?

paragraph_results = soup.find_all('div', class_='st')
print(paragraph_results) # works
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to assume google news class names are going to stay the same?

Comment: Its always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem One**: Flipping the page.

In order to move to the next page you need to include `start` keyword in your URL formatted string:

```py
term = 'cocacola'
page = 2
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={}&source=lnms&tbm=nws&start={}'.format(
    term, (page - 1) * 10
)
```

**Problem Two**: Scraping the headlines.

Google regenerates the names of classes, ids, etc. of DOM elements so your approach is likely to fail every time you retrieve some new, uncached information.

Comment: Thanks and can you please show me how to access headlines?

Comment: For some reason (I do not know why) I get `KeyError: 'page'`...thats strange

Comment: Thanks but I think that name of the classes are always the same. Names for paragraph classes (the one that works in my code) are the same for the past year

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to get the headlines?

Answer (score 1):

Just add parameter 'start=10' to the search term. Like: 
`https://www.google.com/search?q=beatifulsoup&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&start=10`

For dynamic behavior/loop over response pages use something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from request import get

term="beautifulsoup"
page_max = 5

# loop over pages
for page in range(0, page_max):
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&start={}".format(term, 10*page)

    r = get(url) # you can also add headers here
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: But how to make it dynamic,  to have variables `term` and for loop for page `range(1,5)`